# Tableau: show number of occurances of each number on a fixed scale of 1 - 5

Tags: tableau-api

I have data with teacher and student scores (on a scale 1-5).  I want to show how many teacher grades were 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and same with the students grading themselves.

I have the data in 2 formats, in the same row, and pivoted on 2 seperate rows.  ie

Same row like this

```
 student name   |   Teacher Score    |   Student Score
----------------------------------------------------
 Jack                4                     3
 Jim                 2                     3
 Tom                 5                     4
```

Pivoted like this

```
student name  |    Pivot Field     |     Score
-----------------------------------------------------
 Jack              student score          3
 Jack              teacher score          4
 Jim               student score          2
 Jim               teacher score          3
 Tom               student score          4
 Tom               teacher score          5
```

I'm just looking to do this in tableau, count how many of each grading scores were casted by teachers, and students, like this

```
ALL 5 SCORES  |    TOTAL COUNT TEACHER   |   TOTAL COUNT STUDENT
   1                       0                         0            (zero 1's were given out)
   2                       1                         0
   3                       0                         2            (ie both Jack and Jim gave themselves a 3)
   4                       1                         1
   5                       1                         0
```

Does that make sense?  Please let me know if I need to further explain.  I feel like I should know this but I'm stumped and I'm having trouble putting the right words together to search for it.. thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a bin field of your scores. Right click on you score field and select `create` then select `bins`. In the size of bins box change it to 1. Then add the new field to your columns and `number of records` to rows.

[image: using Quantity in place of Score]

Comment: Thanks so much, bins seems to be very close to what I'm looking to do.  Only restrictions I'm running into is a) the current scores are 2,3,4,5 so it doesn't show 1 which I'd like to see with a 0 count next to it.  and b) I was able to get this working for one of the 2 sets of score (ie just Employee or just Manager) but I can't seem to get both teacher and student columns next to each other with the data, they both yield the number of rows for the field I created the bin with.  Thanks so much for this and any further help!

Comment: No problem. To show the missing 1, right click the score(bin) pill on the column shelf and select `show missing values`. That should display any values in a series that appear to be missing. To see the teacher and student scores together, does it work to pull your `pivot` field to the column shelf?